# Complex SELECT IN doesn't work in Oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT d.CREATION_DATE, r.RN5, s.rn1, s.PI1, r.KTR,
       VERSION_NR, getTitle(r.RN5, VERSION_NR) AS TITLE
FROM DOI_SNAPSHOT d, RELATION r, SOURCE_ADDRESS s 
WHERE r.RN1 NOT IN (8010,777) 
    AND d.RN5 = r.RN5 
    AND r.RN1 = s.RN1 
    AND r.RN5 IN (91010008,91010015)
    AND r.RN5 not in (
        SELECT RN5
        FROM RELATION
        WHERE DOI5 IS NOT NULL 
            AND DOI_DATE IS NULL
    ) 
    AND VERSION_NR = (
        SELECT max(VERSION_NR)
        FROM DOI_SNAPSHOT dmax 
        WHERE d.RN5 = dmax.RN5
    );
```

and this query:

```
SELECT substr(w.message, 5, instr(w.message, 'KTR') - 5) AS RN5
FROM WEB_STATISTICS w 
WHERE w.ACTION = 'DOI Display'
GROUP BY substr(w.message, 5, instr(w.message, 'KTR') - 5)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

both of them are working correctly.

Now if I replace the first query's line

```
AND r.RN5 IN (91010008, 91010015)
```

and put in the parenthesis the second query, I get an error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

I don't know what is happening, since both queries are working oracle should at least accept the syntax?

Comment: What is data type of column named `RN5`?

Comment: Data type doesn't matter as it's a syntax error...

Comment: Try removing `order by ...` from inner query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have an order by clause in your second query, and you've left that in when you turned it into a subquery. The clause isn't valid in that context and makes no sense anyway - you're looking for members of a set, the ordering of the elements within that set is irrelevant - so you should remove the `order by count(*) desc` part.

To demonstrate with a simple but very contrived example; with an order by clause:

```
select * from dual
where dummy in (select 'X' from dual order by 1 desc);

SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

And without:

```
select * from dual
where dummy in (select 'X' from dual);

DUMMY
-----
X
```

As a simplistic explanation of the error message, when the parser see the `order by` it thinks that applies to the main query, and therefore the subquery should have already been terminated a closing right parenthesis - which is missing.

This is a message that often doesn't mean what you might think it implies - it isn't that the query overall has unbalanced parentheses, just that it's found a syntax error that may have been caused by a missing or misplaced one.

Answer (score 3):

Generally error ORA-00907 usually means "there is a syntax error somewhere before this point".

Let's try

```
SQL> select * from dual
  2  where dummy in (select dummy from dual);

DUMMY
-----
X

SQL> select * from dual
  2  where dummy in (select dummy from dual order by 1);

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

So you should remove ORDER BY clause from inner query.